# What is the equivalent package of ORMLite used in case of Xamarin.Android application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, ormlite, ormlite-servicestack

In case of Android project ORMLite has been used. I would like to know what is the equivalent package that should be used in case of Xamarin.Android application. From some blogs there is a mention of ServiceStack.OrmLite.

This url: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/tree/master/libs/ServiceStack shows lot of options, but I am not sure which option should be used here.

Can anyone provide me their guidance along with a sample project implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Xamarin.Android projects you can use [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). This is the most used ORM like library in Xamarin.

You can get it from nuget and it's available for all the platforms (.Net based).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :).